# Internal server error after restart apache

Tags: 18.04, server, apache2

I'm receiving this message in log after update the PHP version and restart apache server

```
[Sat Jul 30 18:13:31.561595 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 21950] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Jul 30 18:13:31.788602 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 22000] AH01906: serverexample:8080:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)

[Sat Jul 30 18:13:31.788628 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 22000] AH01909: serverexample:8080:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

[Sat Jul 30 18:13:31.788729 2022] [ssl:error] [pid 22000] AH02217: ssl_stapling_init_cert: can't retrieve issuer certificate! [subject: emailAddress=emailexample,CN=Azya,OU=A$

[Sat Jul 30 18:13:31.788735 2022] [ssl:error] [pid 22000] AH02604: Unable to configure certificate serverexample.com:8080:0 for stapling

[Sat Jul 30 18:13:31.788787 2022] [suexec:notice] [pid 22000] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/lib/apache2/suexec)

[Sat Jul 30 18:13:31.796234 2022] [so:warn] [pid 22000] AH01574: module php7_module is already loaded, skipping

[Sat Jul 30 18:13:31.854987 2022] [:notice] [pid 22017] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 22017)

[Sat Jul 30 18:13:31.908405 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 22014] AH01906: serverexample.com:8080:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)

[Sat Jul 30 18:13:31.908427 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 22014] AH01909: serverexample.com:8080:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

[Sat Jul 30 18:13:31.908504 2022] [ssl:error] [pid 22014] AH02217: ssl_stapling_init_cert: can't retrieve issuer certificate! [subject: emailAddress=emailexample,CN=Azya,OU=A$

[Sat Jul 30 18:13:31.908511 2022] [ssl:error] [pid 22014] AH02604: Unable to configure certificate serverexample.com:8080:0 for stapling

[Sat Jul 30 18:13:31.915120 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 22014] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_fastcgi/mod_fastcgi-SNAP-0910052141 mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.1.1 configured -- $

[Sat Jul 30 18:13:31.915150 2022] [core:notice] [pid 22014] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding

> server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

See your `httpd-ssl.conf` file where you installed apache (likely `/etc/apache2/` and find the `ServerName` parameter (*). Put a `#` in front of it and insert a new line beneath it with `ServerName localhost`. Restart apache and this error message should be gone.

(*) Your line probably has `serverexample.com:8080:0` and that is not going to be your url plus the `:0` behind the `:8080` is wrong.

If this does not fix it you will have another config set using `serverexample.com:8080:0`. Change that one to localhost and remove the `:0`.

Comment: I've found no httpd-ssl.conf, i've checked all folders, but found nothinh

Comment: more importantly is to find the `serverexample.com:8080:0`  it will be in one of the config files you used and that needs to be replaced by localhost or the actual server.